# How do you fix the passive voice in this sentence

Tags: passive-voice, hypercorrection, software-bugs

I wrote this sentence:

Because of his low weight, Gabe **was still being nurtured** instead of being named.

And Word underlined the bold part saying I was using passive voice and I don't know how to fix it.

Passive voice is not part of the assignment, but I need two prepositional phrases.

Comment: 1. Click the round Office button in the upper-left corner of the window.
2. Click the Word Options button.
3. Click Proofing.
4. Click the Settings button.
5. In the Grammar and style options list box, scroll down and find and uncheck the Passive sentences item.
6. Click OK.

You didn't have a grammar problem, you had a software problem.

Comment: There is nothing to fix! It's a perfectly fine sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Gabe is a small baby and thus does nothing, you need to bring in another subject to avoid passive voice.  His parents, his mother, his doctors....

Comment: He is nurtured by a character named Jacob, how could I use that to make a non passive-voice sentence.

Comment: "Jacob nurtured the infant carefully and because of his low weight, did not even name him."

Comment: But the homework assignment said I have to use 2 prepositional phrases

Comment: So add some more!